# What are the differences between the code wrapped in useEffect(fn, []) and the code outside useEffect(fn, [])?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

The new **React Hooks** feature is cool but it sometimes makes me confused. In particular, I have this code wrapped in `useEffect` hook:

```
const compA = ({ num }) => {
  const [isPositive, check] = useState(false);
  useEffect(() => {
    if (num > 0) check(true); 
  }, []);

  return (//...JSX);
};
```

The code inside the above `useEffect` will be executed only once. So what are the differences if I bring the code out of the `useEffect`, like below:

```
const compA = ({ num }) => {
  const [isPositive, check] = useState(false);

  if (num > 0) check(true);

  return (//...JSX);
};
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

in the second case the code will be executed at every re-render.

this is a better version of the component:

```
const compA = ({ num }) => {
  const [isPositive, check] = useState(false);
  useEffect(() => {
    if (num > 0) check(true); 
  }, [num]);

  return (//...JSX);
};
```

In this case the effect (which depends heavily on **num**) is used only when the num prop has changed.

for reference:
https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#conditionally-firing-an-effect

Anyway, in my opinion using a side effect in this very simple case is overkill!
The code will run faster by checking if `num > 0` at every render than checking first if num changed and then if it's > 0..
So you should probably just avoid `useEffect` and stick to your second piece of code

Comment: Ah! Thanks! It's just an example for my question, btw, thanks for your advice.

Comment: Yes, I was guessing so, but it's still a good example for learning :)
Remember for the future that useEffect should be used only (as the name suggests) for side effects, in other words when you have to deal with variables or make actions that don't depend on the props, for example data resulting from an api call